# reformatting datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format

I have data "A" in the format chr "5/7/2021 15:15". I would like to convert it to a format which R will recognize. (It is giving me errors when I try to plot, for instance, which leads me to believe it needs to be reformatted.)

Here is the format "B" I would like to achieve. R seems to like this ok, so I might as well match it (?):

POSIXct, format: "2021-8-11 16:00:00". I am not sure if the seconds are needed, and they do not exist in data "A" so the seconds could be omitted. If R doesn't care then I don't either. The timezone is UTC.

How do I do it? I have tried a couple things, including:

```
CTD_datetime_UTC <- as.POSIXct(CTD$Date.and.Time, tz = "UTC").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strptime` from base R. But there are many parsers for dates...

Assuming the format is "day/month/year" (example is not unambiguous, could also be "month/day/year")

```
strptime("5/7/2021 15:15", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

Returns:

> ```
> [1] "2021-07-05 15:15:00 UTC"
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I had to switch the "d" and the "m" in the code you provided but it otherwise worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `parsedate`

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date("5/7/2021 15:15")
[1] "2021-05-07 15:15:00 UTC"
```